# Why is the motion of a copper plate damped when it is allowed to oscillate between the magnetic pole-pieces? How are Eddy currents involved?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Can anyone explain this to me, **in simple terms**, why the motion of a copper plate is damped when it is allowed to oscillate between the magnetic pole pieces?

Answer (score 0):

In diagram a) Eddy currents are created, this causes a force on the copper plate, the direction of the force can be calculated from Fleming's Left Hand Rule.

[image]

from [Lumen Physics, with more detail](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/23-4-eddy-currents-and-magnetic-damping/)

The direction of the force has to cause damping.  If the force were opposite the motion would increase, causing more Eddy currents, creating more motion etc... in violation of the conservation of energy.
Lenz's law also states that "the direction of the induced e.m.f. is such as to oppose the change producing it".

The copper plate is in diagram a) in b) the slotted pendulum has reduced Eddy currents and less damping, c) is a non conducting plate and there is no damping.